# Magento 2 category updated programmatically not working

Tags: category, magento2.2, programmatically

from upload the CSV file trying to created&update the category, while I create the category from the below script it's working, but while I update the category with the same script does not work. 
I have two store, first store id is 1, then the second store id is 2, in the uploaded CSV I have mentioned that store_id in that

```
 $categoryFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $categoryRepository = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface');
    $categoryCollection = $categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $data['id'])->setPageSize(1);
    if ($categoryCollection->getSize()) {
        $categoryId = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getEntityId(); 
        $category = $categoryRepository->get($categoryId, 0);
    } else {
        $category = $categoryFactory->create();
    }
     if(isset($data[store_id']) && !empty($data['store_id']))
            $category->setStoreId((int)$data['store_id']);
else
             $category->setStoreId(1);

    $category->setName($data['name']);
    if ($isParent) {
        $category->setParentId(2);
    } else {
        $categoryCollection = $categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $data['parent_id'])->setPageSize(1);
        if ($categoryCollection->getSize()) {
            $categoryId = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
            $category->setParentId($categoryId);
        } 
    }
    $category->setIsActive($data['is_active']);
    $category->setIsAnchor($data['is_anchor']);
    $category->setIncludeInMenu($data['include_in_menu']);
    $category->setCustomUseParentSettings($data['custom_use_parent_settings']);

    // will set meta details
    foreach ($this->additionalHeaders as $header) {
        if (array_key_exists($header, $this->headersMap)) {
            $additionalData[$header] = $data[$this->headersMap[$header]];
        }
    }
    $category->setCustomAttributes($additionalData);
    $categoryRepository->save($category);
```

for your further information, I have updated the screens, kindly check and let me share your ideas and thoughts, thanks in advance for your support

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you checking in correct store scope ?

Comment: have tried to clear cache and re-index ?

Comment: right now I am working with the single store, setStoreId(1)

Comment: i checked with all the commands, still same issue